# Unknown warnings while running selenium script using python

Tags: python, selenium, operating-system, filesystems

I am getting these warnings while running my selenium script: -

[image]

All my chrome options: -

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
"download.default_directory": r'C:\webdriver',
"download.prompt_for_download": False,
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=3')
chrome_options.add_argument("--output=/dev/null")
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-software-rasterizer")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
chrome_options.add_argument("--silent")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

What's the reason for these warnings? I got these for the first time.